# Python Class - why do I have to set my class variable equal to itself when setting instance variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance-variables

I am working through Udacity's Artificial Intelligence course for Robotics and came across something puzzling. The course has written a robot class for us to use (I take no credit for this code).

There is a `set` method which is used to set the x,y & orientation of the robot which are parameters within the class. The robot is initialized at `(30,50,pi/2)` in the 2D world and after two movements of `(-pi/2, 15)` and `(-pi/2, 10)` the sense function should estimate ~ `[32.0156, 53.1507, 47.1699, 40.3112]` as the distance to the landmarks. In the driver code at the bottom, I'm finding my answers differ depending on whether I set the class instance equal to itself after the `.set()` method. And I can't figure out why this would matter. I figured the `.set()` method would update that instance of the class's variables. Without the equal signs I get a sense estimate of `[31.6227, 58.3095, 31.6227, 58.3095]`.

The driver code I'm talking about is:

```
myrobot = robot()
myrobot.set(30, 50, pi/2)
myrobot = myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 15)
print(myrobot.sense())
myrobot = myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 10)
print(myrobot.sense())
```

VS...

```
myrobot = robot()
myrobot.set(30, 50, pi/2)
myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 15)
print(myrobot.sense())
myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 10)
print(myrobot.sense())
```

ROBOT CLASS:

```
# Make a robot called myrobot that starts at
# coordinates 30, 50 heading north (pi/2).
# Have your robot turn clockwise by pi/2, move
# 15 m, and sense. Then have it turn clockwise
# by pi/2 again, move 10 m, and sense again.
#
# Your program should print out the result of
# your two sense measurements.
#
# Don't modify the code below. Please enter
# your code at the bottom.

from math import *
import random



landmarks  = [[20.0, 20.0], [80.0, 80.0], [20.0, 80.0], [80.0, 20.0]]
world_size = 100.0


class robot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.random() * world_size
        self.y = random.random() * world_size
        self.orientation = random.random() * 2.0 * pi
        self.forward_noise = 0.0;
        self.turn_noise    = 0.0;
        self.sense_noise   = 0.0;

    def set(self, new_x, new_y, new_orientation):
        if new_x < 0 or new_x >= world_size:
            raise (ValueError, 'X coordinate out of bound')
        if new_y < 0 or new_y >= world_size:
            raise (ValueError, 'Y coordinate out of bound')
        if new_orientation < 0 or new_orientation >= 2 * pi:
            raise (ValueError, 'Orientation must be in [0..2pi]')
        self.x = float(new_x)
        self.y = float(new_y)
        self.orientation = float(new_orientation)


    def set_noise(self, new_f_noise, new_t_noise, new_s_noise):
        # makes it possible to change the noise parameters
        # this is often useful in particle filters
        self.forward_noise = float(new_f_noise);
        self.turn_noise    = float(new_t_noise);
        self.sense_noise   = float(new_s_noise);


    def sense(self):
        Z = []
        for i in range(len(landmarks)):
            dist = sqrt((self.x - landmarks[i][0]) ** 2 + (self.y - landmarks[i][1]) ** 2)
            dist += random.gauss(0.0, self.sense_noise)
            Z.append(dist)
        return Z


    def move(self, turn, forward):
        if forward < 0:
            raise (ValueError, 'Robot cant move backwards')         

        # turn, and add randomness to the turning command
        orientation = self.orientation + float(turn) + random.gauss(0.0, self.turn_noise)
        orientation %= 2 * pi

        # move, and add randomness to the motion command
        dist = float(forward) + random.gauss(0.0, self.forward_noise)
        x = self.x + (cos(orientation) * dist)
        y = self.y + (sin(orientation) * dist)
        x %= world_size    # cyclic truncate
        y %= world_size

        # set particle
        res = robot()
        res.set(x, y, orientation)
        res.set_noise(self.forward_noise, self.turn_noise, self.sense_noise)
        return res

    def Gaussian(self, mu, sigma, x):

        # calculates the probability of x for 1-dim Gaussian with mean mu and var. sigma
        return exp(- ((mu - x) ** 2) / (sigma ** 2) / 2.0) / sqrt(2.0 * pi * (sigma ** 2))


    def measurement_prob(self, measurement):

        # calculates how likely a measurement should be

        prob = 1.0;
        for i in range(len(landmarks)):
            dist = sqrt((self.x - landmarks[i][0]) ** 2 + (self.y - landmarks[i][1]) ** 2)
            prob *= self.Gaussian(dist, self.sense_noise, measurement[i])
        return prob



    def __repr__(self):
        return '[x=%.6s y=%.6s orient=%.6s]' % (str(self.x), str(self.y), str(self.orientation))



def eval(r, p):
    sum = 0.0;
    for i in range(len(p)): # calculate mean error
        dx = (p[i].x - r.x + (world_size/2.0)) % world_size - (world_size/2.0)
        dy = (p[i].y - r.y + (world_size/2.0)) % world_size - (world_size/2.0)
        err = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
        sum += err
    return sum / float(len(p))



####   DON'T MODIFY ANYTHING ABOVE HERE! ENTER CODE BELOW ####

myrobot = robot()
myrobot.set(30, 50, pi/2)
myrobot = myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 15)
print(myrobot.sense())
myrobot = myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 10)
print(myrobot.sense())
```

Comment: `robot.move` returns a new robot instance, it doesn't seem to modify the instance it's called on. In contrast, `robot.set` modifies the current instance's `x` and `y` attributes directly. For what it's worth (given my lack of context), it seems strange to me that it's done this way.

Comment: "whether I set the class instance equal to itself after the ...". You're not setting it to itself (`myrobot = myrobot`), you're setting it to the result of the `.move` method, which gives you a totally new robot instance.

Comment: Ah. I see what you're saying. @TomDalton I also find it odd that in the move function creates a new instance of robot. Is that normal? Isn't a huge benefit of OOP being able to maintain instance variables?

Comment: Yes, it seems strange to me, especially when set doesn't give a new robot but modifies the existing one. There might be good reasons for the inconsistent behaviour, maybe relating to the environment in which this code is being used, but I don't know what they might be. You could raise it through Udacity's forums/help/whatever they offer, it might be an interesting answer, or it might just be a mistake or poor design.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.) myrobot = robot()
    myrobot.set(30, 50, pi/2)
    myrobot = myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 15)
    print(myrobot.sense())
    myrobot = myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 10)
    print(myrobot.sense())
```

In the above code, you are doing correct as per the question asked that is, setting the robot at (30,50, pi/2) and sense after one move and again sense after second move.

Since **move** method is returning a new instance that is now moved from its original position(i.e. at [30,50,pi/2]) **or** you can say that in **move** method position of myrobot object is not set but the programmer is setting position of new instance (i.e. res).
So the position of myrobot that you declared will remain same, so to avoid this, you need to re-instantiate with the object returned by the **move** method.

```
2.) myrobot = robot()
    myrobot.set(30, 50, pi/2)
    myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 15)
    print(myrobot.sense())
    myrobot.move(-(pi/2), 10)
    print(myrobot.sense())
```

However, in the 2.) code, you will get the same result of ***sense*** even after you moved the robot two times.
The result of the above two print instruction in 2.) code will be same as when you set the robot at (30,50, pi/2) and it is remained same, because in **move** method, new instance is being created and position of this new instance is being changed.

Since the attributes you are changing is not the class attributes(i.e. x,y and orientation are not common to every object).
That is why, by changing attributes for one object will not change the corresponding attributes of other object. since every instance of a class has their own copy of attributes and methods.